# FindBugs: Suspicious comparison of Double references

Tags: java, double, findbugs, boxing, reference-type

I have a method that takes two `Doubles` `a` and `b` (note the capital 'D') and calculates the difference. If only one of the parameters is `null`, the result shall be `999999`, otherwise the difference between both numbers is to be returned.

The following (working) code gives me a "scary" warning in FindBugs, and I usually try to avoid high ranked warnings in the code. However, I think the code both short and readable, and everything else I can think just makes it less readable. IMHO using `==` is perfectly correct in *this* case.

```
public double foo(Double a, Double b) {
    return a == b ? 0 : (a != null && b != null) ? b - a : 999999;
}
```

And the FindBugs report for that line:

> Bug: Suspicious comparison of Double references in
>   Main.foo(Double, Double)
>
> This method compares two reference values using the == or != operator,
>   where the correct way to compare instances of this type is generally
>   with the equals() method. It is possible to create distinct instances
>   that are equal but do not compare as == since they are different
>   objects. Examples of classes which should generally not be compared by
>   reference are java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Float, etc.
>
> Confidence: High, Rank: Scariest (1) Pattern: RC_REF_COMPARISON  Type:
>   RC, Category: CORRECTNESS (Correctness)

Any idea how to rewrite this code clean and simple without warnings?

Comment: Not directly related, but other code-checking tools like PMD will complain about the "magic number" you have there (999999), because it's not clear what it means and if you have to use it elsewhere, it's easy to mistype (Harmlezz answer has it as 9999, for example :-)). Better to use a constant with a meaningfull name like DIFFERENCE_WHEN_NULL or MAX_DIFFERENCE

Comment: Yes, that's right of course.

Comment: After thinking about that for a while, i suppose your code is correct if you want `foo(null,null)` to yield `0.0d` as result. Usually, comparing `Double` objects using `==` indicates an programmers mistake (`==` compares the references, not the `Double`s values!). So you may ignore FindBugs warning for this special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest more steps to do the same, easy maintenance in the long run

```
public double foo(Double a, Double b) {

    //as per Marco suggestion. but not sure OP wants the same.
    if(a == null && b == null){
          return 0;
    } 
    //END
    if(a == null || b == null){
          return 999999;
    }    
    return b-a;  //will return 0 if they are equal. no extra checks required
}
```

Comment: Based on the initial code, it seems that comparing two `null`s should yield `0` and not `999999`...

Comment: Indeed, this may be considered as more concise than my answer for this case. To justify my two-step-approach: I still wonder whether something like `d(null,b) = -Infinity` and `d(a,null) = +Infinity` might not be more appropriate, but that's something that only the asker can decide....

Comment: Ok, I settled for this. Thank you. @Marco13 I left the magic number 999999 in. The code is used to create an excel table with comparison results, and `+/-Infinity` is displayed as `?`.

Comment: @Axel Then you might alternatively consider `Double.MAX_VALUE` and `-Double.MAX_VALUE`, but I don't know what excel will make out of this...

Answer (score 2):

`==` check both reference are referring same object or not. But, You have to check both having same value or not. So use `.equals()` method

```
public double foo(Double a, Double b) {
    return (a != null && a.equals(b)) ? 0 : (a != null && b != null) ? b - a : 999999;
}
```

Comment: This may cause a NullPointerException at `a.equals(`

Comment: @ Harmlezz And what about a == b?

Comment: Have a look at my (dirty) solution :) But it works (ternary terror)

Comment: Checking for reference equality is alright here. It just catches the case of both parameters being `null`. If both have the same value, the subtraction will give 0 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> ... and everything else I can think just makes it less readable

Depending on whether you prefer readability over correctness or not, you could consider

```
public double foo(Double a, Double b) 
{
    if (a == null)
    {
        if (b == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 999999;
    }
    if (b == null)
    {
        return 999999;
    }
    return b - a;
}
```

BTW: This `999999` looks suspicious. Maybe this should rather be `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Double.MAX_VALUE` or so, but sure it depends on the intended usage.

Comment: You don't need so much of duplicated code. check my solution. simple and straight-forward

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to your answer: That depends on whether comparing two `null` values should yied `0` or `999999` (that does not mean that the code could not be written *shorter*, but I think my solution is clear and easy to understand. I don't like nested ternary `?:` statements and other gymnastics. Code should read like prose.

Answer (score 1):

How about this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(null, null);
    print(5.0, null);
    print(null, 2.0);
    print(5.0, 2.0);
}

public static void print(Double a, Double b) {
    System.out.printf("a=%f, b=%f result=%f\n", a, b, foo(a, b));
}

public static double foo(Double a, Double b) {
    return a == null
            ? b == null ? 0 : 9999
            : b == null ? 9999 : b - a;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
a=null,     b=null     result=0.000000
a=5.000000, b=null     result=9999.000000
a=null,     b=2.000000 result=9999.000000
a=5.000000, b=2.000000 result=-3.000000
```